# error: array type 'va_list' (aka '__builtin_va_list') is not assignable

Tags: c, java-native-interface, swig

What should i do to make it assignable? I have auto-generated the JNI function from this function which was in header file. Here is the function declaration in header file *

> char* stringFormatV(const char* format, va_list args);

```
    SWIGEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_jnisourceJNI_stringFormatV(JNIEnv
        *jenv, jclass jcls, jstring jarg1, jlong jarg2) {
              jstring jresult = 0 ;
              char *arg1 = (char *) 0 ;
              va_list arg2 ;
              va_list *argp2 ;
              char *result = 0 ;

              (void)jenv;
              (void)jcls;
              arg1 = 0;
              if (jarg1) {
                arg1 = (char *)(*jenv)->GetStringUTFChars(jenv, jarg1, 0);
                if (!arg1) return 0;
              }
              argp2 = *(va_list **)&jarg2; 
              if (!argp2) {
                SWIG_JavaThrowException(jenv, SWIG_JavaNullPointerException, "Attempt to dereference null va_list");
                return 0;
              }
              arg2 = *argp2; //here is the problem
              result = (char *)stringFormatV((char const *)arg1,arg2);
              if (result) jresult = (*jenv)->NewStringUTF(jenv, (const char *)result);
              if (arg1) (*jenv)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jenv, jarg1, (const char *)arg1);
              return jresult;
            }
```

at this line compiler gives error

> arg2 = *argp2; //here is the problem

Comment: so what should i do ? should i remove the line ?

Comment: What is the function you show supposed to do? Perhaps is should be a *proper* variable-argument function? And if that's not possible, then perhaps a redesign might be in order?

Comment: `argp2 = *(va_list **)&jarg2; ` -- What in the world ..???  Take a step back -- unravel all of those casts.  Read the compiler errors when you remove the cast.  What does the error state?  Whatever it is, *take heed and understand it*.  Don't cover up the errors by applying casts to "shut the compiler up".

Comment: I have autogenerated the JNI code from header file . basically i am generating the java wrapers for JNI calls. i don't know what is happening in the function. i am not c expert :p

Comment: If the code you show is auto-generated, then what is it auto-generated *from*? Please show the SWIG input needed for the creation of such a function. And also tell us if this is something you wrote yourself, or if it's something you found or if it's part of a project or library that you want to use.

Comment: [See here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93d6d5fea60051d2).  That 3 line program that performs the operation you're having trouble with doesn't compile.  If this is really autogenerated, why would the generator assume that `va_list` is assignable? (unless the code is meant for a certain compiler that by chance makes `va_list`'s assignable).

Comment: char* stringFormatV(const char* format, va_list args); this the function from which i have autogenerated

Comment: Now how to make it assignable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to [read the variable length argument documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Varargs.html). Especially the section about [wrapping `va_list`](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Varargs.html#Varargs_nn8) which states

> As far as we know, there is no obvious way to wrap these functions with SWIG.

In short, it's not really possible.

The only solution I can see is to provide a variable-argument function which SWIG generate a function for, and this vararg function calls the real `stringFormatV` function.

Comment: As i can understand you are saying that i should modify the function which is char* stringFormatV(const char* format, ...); like this and then generate a function for this and then pas the arguments in real stringFormatV function ?

Comment: Can you please help to write this as i am not C expert, i work on java

Comment: @MushahidGillani No, I say that you should create a new `char* stringFormat(const char* format, ...)` function (note the lack of `V` in the name). This function will properly create a `va_list` and then call `stringFormatV`. You use the varargs `stringFormat` in SWIG. Unless this function `stringFormat` already exists, then use that.

Comment: char* stringFormat(const char* format, ...);  swig is generating it with one argument only i.e it becomes static native String stringFormat(String jarg1); in java

Comment: @MushahidGillani Did you read the documentation I linked to? It says that what you see is the default behavior. There are workarounds, but you have to read about it. Please.